# New digitizer stopped working after 30 seconds

Tags: ipod-touch, digitizer

I plugged a brand new digitizer into my 2g iPod touch and I wanted to test it before I clip it in. It worked great at first and I managed to click with it for about 30 seconds, while not moving the digitizer or the iPod.

Suddenly, it stopped working and I have been unable to get the digitizer to work again, despite reseating it numerous times. The iPod works otherwise normally.

What happened?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that both sides of the connect cable a plugged in, then make sure that the center button works.  The center button has broke for many of my friends and myself.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a digitizer die on me after a few weeks of use. I replaced the digitizer in my iPhone 3GS and it worked like a charm until one side of it just stop responding one day. (Being an iOS dev, I whipped together an app that had number buttons on only half the screen, so I was able to still use it.)

I'd suggest checking the cables. Be sure that you didn't loosen anything while "testing before refastening".

Also, considering the fragile nature of both the device and the non-apple digitizer, it could be broken. If the cables are all connected, you might need to send it back to where you bought it.